# nil delegate in modal view after presentViewController.

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

My first view in the viewDidLoad has the following code

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Dialpad" bundle:nil];
self.vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DialpadBoard"];
self.vc.delegate = self;
```

The header file contains the definition of the view controller

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) DialpadTableViewController *vc;
```

after catching an event the view loads a new modal view

```
- (void)handleEvent:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    [self presentViewController:self.vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The view also contains the method to dismiss the modal view:

```
- (void) dialpadControllerDidCancel:(SearchDialpadTableViewController *)controller {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The last method never gets called.

The problem is that the modal view when it is loaded has nil self.delegate. The new modal view is loaded from the storyboard as seen below. Why the delegate is nil? I cannot how a segue since the view is in another storyboard.
[image]

Comment: did you implement the "dismiss" method in first view controller?

Comment: yes, it is implemented, however it never gets called, because the second view controller has self.delegate nil.

Comment: if you just implement this method to dismiss the second view you can choose easier way , insert uibutton at second view and as dismiss button

Comment: but if you want to dismiss the second view after some events you need to   define a delegate protocol at second view to call your method

Comment: I have done that. My problem is that the second view does not have the address of the first view (self.delegate is nil) and this is my main problem

Comment: did you add the delegate name at your header ?

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <yourdelegate>

Comment: yes, the delegate is defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93497/discussion-between-engmahsa-and-cateof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Dialpad" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController *nav= [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DialpadBoard"];




((SearchDialpadTableViewController *)[nav viewControllers][0]).delegate = self; 
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Since we have the nav let's take the first controller and assign the delegate

the trick ;)

```
((SearchDialpadTableViewController *)[nav viewControllers][0]).delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `SearchDialpadTableViewController` define a delegate protocol and does it have a property that is specific to that protocol?

The header for that file should look something like:

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegateProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)dialpadControllerDidCancel:(SearchDialpadTableViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ViewControllerDelegateProtocol> searchPadDelegate;

@end
```

Then when the user taps `Done` which is I'm assuming what you're trying to do (send a delegate message when that happens). You would write something like

```
- (IBAction)donePressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.searchPadDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialpadControllerDidCancel)]) {
        [self.searchPadDelegate dialpadControllerDidCancel:self];
}
}
```

Comment: Everything is as you describe, with the difference that the delegate is not weak but strong, since the project does not use ARC.

Comment: my donePressed method contains [self.delegate dialpadControllerDidCancel:self]; but here the self.delegate is nil so I cannot return to the first view.

Comment: Id encourage you to update your initial question with the aforementioned code so that it can be checked for errors.

Answer (score 0):

you must be certain, that self.vc is a class, that you expected. It can be also NavigationController